# Vertical spacing between two lines of an item

Tags: lists, enumerate, line-spacing, enumitem

I encountered a problem regarding the spacing between two lines of an item when wrapping a row of text.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.

Some wrapped text some wrapped text some wrapped text some wrapped text:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text.

    Here lies the problem.

    \item Some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text.
\end{enumerate}
Some boring text again some boring text again some boring text again. 

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following image as an output:

[image]

As can be seen, the vertical space between the lines of the top text is different than the one between the lines of the first item.

I could fix it by using the `enumitem` package and setting `parsep=0pt`, but doing so also changes the spacing between the two items, which is given by `\itemsep + \parsep`, and I don't want that.

Another way could be to set a negative vertical space before the wrapped line using the `\vspace{}` command, but I'm unable to find the correct value of vertical space to remove and it also feels a bit sloppy to me.

How can I get correct line spacing for the wrapped line of the item, by maintaining all other spacings the same?

Thank you for your time, it is very appreciated.

Comment: this is intended (deliberately designed) features. i would not change it. however, using `enumitem` you can easily changes vertical distances by defining new values for `topsep`, `partopsep`, `parsep` and `itemsep`.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks, I've tried setting parsep=0pt but by doing so it also changes the spacing between items, and I don't want that to happen. It's the first time I use an enumerate environment so I very likely might have misunderstood something.

Comment: unfortunately documentation of `enumitem` doesn't contain image of lists layout. so you need to find it somewhere else, that you will see what define each mentioned distances . if you have installed `memoir` package, you will find it on page 137 of its documentation.

Comment: @Zarko, that's unfortunate, thank you again for your time.

Comment: you can also find sketch of list layout on http://texblog.net/latex-beginners-guide/examples/chapter-4/

Comment: @Zarko perhaps a feature request? https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem

Comment: @daleif, yes,.  unfortunately i'm not familiar nor user of the github. i think about to write to the author, but so far i didn't  gathered enough courage to write  him ;-(. i will be very glad if you or some else  (more skilled than me to do this)  will make this.

Comment: @Zarko added, https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem/issues/15, let me know if you have anything else worth adding to it.

Comment: @daleif, thank you very much!  this additions will be very helpful to beginners. so far I haven't any other suggestion

Comment: @Zarko I think even veterans will benefit having a visual image of what is used where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `\parsep` to 0pt, and increase the value of `\itemsep` of the default value of \parsep (5pt). Also add paragraph indent inside the list. All this is easy with package `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.

Some wrapped text some wrapped text some wrapped text some wrapped text some wrapped text:

\begin{enumerate}[parsep = 0pt, listparindent=1em, itemsep=10pt]
    \item Some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text.

    A problem? What problem?

    \item Some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text.
\end{enumerate}
Some boring text again some boring text again some boring text again.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text.

    Here lies the problem.

    \item Some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that the indentation in a 12pt document is of 1.5em. I read it somewhere, can't remember where though.

Comment: I guess this is an American standard. I'm using a European  standard, which looks better in my opinion for a list (there's already a global indentation of the list…)